# Tornado request.body

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

My Tornado application accepts POST data through http body request

In my handler I am able to get the request

```
def post(self):
    data = self.request.body
```

The data I am getting is in the from of str(dictionary)

Is there a way to receive this data in the form of a Python dictionary?

I don't want to use `eval` on the server side to convert this string to a Python dictionary.

Comment: It's probably a JSON string.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this json string to python dictionary without using eval.

Comment: This json string involves spaces which does not other json libraries to con ver it into python dictionar

Comment: Can you post a sample?

Comment: {  \n        \"_id\" : \"cd4cca2_9vg5jyuwqxgmxfr\", \n        \"time\" : '2012-01-01', \n        \"opening_type\" : \"Recall\", \n            }"

Comment: How are you generating this?

Comment: I am doing a json dump on request.body. json.dumps(self.request.body)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29621/discussion-between-joel-james-and-blender)

Comment: Tornado isn't generating that string, rather whatever is posting to your app is..

Answer (score 53):

As an alternative to Eloim's answer, Tornado provides [tornado.escape](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/escape.html) for "Escaping/unescaping HTML, JSON, URLs, and others".  Using it should give you exactly what you want:

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I receive the error: in json_decode
    return json.loads(to_basestring(value))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 23):

You are receiving a JSON string.
Decode it with the JSON module

```
import json

def post(self):
    data = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

For more info: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: in Python3 you have to decode the original bytestring, for eg.  `json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: You can now use `tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)` which will handle all the decoding for you.

Comment: Note that using `tornado.escape` wrappers to `json.loads` means you will be unable to customize/override `JSONDecoder` with `cls` or `parse_...` kwargs. (This is way more of an issue with using the complementary `tornado.escape.json.encode` that wraps `json.dumps`. but is still worth mentioning here.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar issue when I was parsing requests in Tornado.  Try using the urllib.unquote_plus module:

```
import urllib
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json


data = json.loads(urllib.unquote_plus(self.request.body))
```

My code had to be prepared for both different formats of request, so I did something like:

```
try:
    json.loads(self.request.body)
except:
    json.loads(urllib.unquote_plus(self.request.body))
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what the answer was, so let me know if this helped (or if you figured it out in chat).  I'm almost positive that it was because it was url-encoded.

Comment: Escaping helped me here.

Comment: For python3, it's `urllib.parse.unquote_plus()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebApp2, it uses its own json extras. (Decode)
http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/webapp2_extras/json.html

```
    data = json.decode(self.request.body)
    v = data.get(key)   
    self.response.write(v)
```

For example my post key is 'postvalue'

```
    data = json.decode(self.request.body)
    v = data.get('postvalue')   
    self.response.write(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
bind_args = dict((k,v[-1] ) for k, v in self.request.arguments.items())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Or `{ k : v[-1] for k, v in self.request.arguments.items() }`

Answer (score -1):

Best way for me to parse body in tornado built-in `httputil`
Good work with multi input (like checkbox, tables, etc.).
If submit elements have same name in dictionary returning list of values.

Working sample:

```
import tornado.httputil    

    def post(self):
        file_dic = {}
        arg_dic = {}

        tornado.httputil.parse_body_arguments('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', self.request.body, arg_dic, file_dic)

    print(arg_dic, file_dic)  # or other code`
```