# Http post request in Angular2 does not pass parameters

Tags: json, post, angular, typescript

I am trying to send a parameter using Angular2 POST to my Python/Tornado back-end which returns a JSON object. The parameters are being sent properly but at the Python side, it is returning 400 POST missing arguments error. I am using Ionic 2/Angular2 in the front-end and Python/Tornado server.

Angular2 code is as follows: 
Here content is a variable containing HTML table

```
let body = JSON.stringify({content: content});
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post(url, body, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
}, error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Python code is as follows:

```
def post(self):
    print self.request.arguments
    print self.get_argument('content')
    self.finish(dict(result="ok", data=content))
```

Here is the error:

```
[W 160824 06:04:30 web:1493] 400 POST /test (182.69.5.99): Missing argument content
[W 160824 06:04:30 web:1908] 400 POST /test (182.69.5.99) 1.67ms
```

Comment: Are you sure content is not undefined before your js code snippet ?

Comment: What if you do `let body = JSON.stringify({content: content || ''})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Angular2 code looks reasonable, however your Python code is wrong, because you are treating the request as x-www-form-urlencoded. You have to access the JSON string through the request.body property:

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28140966/2380400 for an answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try to use something like URLSearchParams() with an URLencoded content type. I don't know much about Tornado but I am using ASP controllers and it works fine.

See Angular2 Documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html

Watch the following authentication example I am using :

```
controllerURL: string = "/APIConnexion";

login(aLogin: string, aMdp: string) {
        // parameters definition (has to have the same name on the controller)
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set("aLogin", aLogin);
        params.set("aMdp", aMdp);
        // setup http request
        let lHttpRequestBody = params.toString();
        let lControllerAction: string = "/connexion";
        let lControllerFullURL: string = this.controllerURL + lControllerAction;
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        // call http
        return this.http.post(lControllerFullURL, lHttpRequestBody, options)
            .map((res: any) => {
                // data received as JSON
                let data = res.json();

                // Do something with your data

            }
            ).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```